# How to set default value checked for checkbox in meta box

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, meta-boxes

I know this question were appeared a lot of times, but I can't find the answer for me.
I have simple checkbox and everything working fine, except that default value is always empty.
Here my code:

```
function portfolio_additional_settings($post) {
        $meta_port_cats = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_portfolio_meta_cats', true);
        wp_nonce_field( 'update_portfolio_additional_settings', 'update_portfolio_additional_nonce' );
            ?>
        <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="portfolio_meta_cats_field" id="portfolio_meta_cats_field" value="1" <?php checked($meta_port_cats, 1); ?> />
                    <label for="portfolio_meta_cats_field"><?php esc_html_e( 'Categories', 'portfolio' ); ?></label>
        </div>
}

function save_portfolio_additional_settings($post_id, $post) {

            $edit_cap = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type )->cap->edit_post;
            if( !current_user_can( $edit_cap, $post_id )) {
                return;
            }
            if( !isset( $_POST['update_portfolio_additional_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['update_portfolio_additional_nonce'], 'update_portfolio_additional_settings' )) {
                return;
            }

            if(array_key_exists('portfolio_meta_cats_field', $_POST)) {
                update_post_meta( 
                    $post_id, 
                    '_portfolio_meta_cats', 
                    sanitize_text_field($_POST['portfolio_meta_cats_field'])
                );
            } else {
                update_post_meta( 
                    $post_id, 
                    '_portfolio_meta_cats', null);
            }
    }
        add_action( 'save_post', 'save_portfolio_additional_settings', 10, 2 );
```

How can I pass checked by default? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as follows:

```php
<input type="checkbox" 
       name="portfolio_meta_cats_field" 
       id="portfolio_meta_cats_field" 
       value="<?php echo $meta_port_cats; ?>" 
       <?php if ($meta_port_cats === '1'): ?>checked<?php endif; ?> />
```

Comment: Sorry, but the same result as I have